# listview does not show some item

Tags: android, listview

Good afternoon!
listview does not show some items on some devices. Between some items there are empty space.

Imageview (i'm using universal image loader) and textview are loading of internet.
If you reduce the quality of the images on the server, then item be. I do not understand how it is works

getView :

```
       View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (v == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_layout_item, null);

        viewHolder.text_group = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.group);
        viewHolder.text_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
        viewHolder.author = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.author);
        viewHolder.addition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.addition);
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        viewHolder.ico_group = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ico_group);

        viewHolder.text_group.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-M.ttf"));
        viewHolder.text_date.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-N.ttf"));
        viewHolder.title.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-M.ttf"));
        viewHolder.text.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-L.ttf"));
        viewHolder.author.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-N.ttf"));
        viewHolder.addition.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset
                (context.getAssets(), "Ubuntu-N.ttf"));
        viewHolder.text.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("size_preview", "15")));
        viewHolder.pos = position;
        v.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text_group.setText(themetext(data.get(position).get(NAMEGROUP).toString()));
    viewHolder.text_date.setText(data.get(position).get(DATE).toString());
    viewHolder.title.setText(data.get(position).get(HEADER).toString());
    viewHolder.text.setText(ExtraClass.text_clear(data.get(position).get(CONTENT).toString()));
    viewHolder.author.setText(data.get(position).get(AUTHOR).toString());
    ExtraClass.setIco(data.get(position).get(NAMEGROUP).toString(), viewHolder.ico_group, context);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            //.showStubImage(R.drawable.notif)
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).get(IMG).toString(), viewHolder.img, options);

    return v;
```

all appearances, images does not loading only large. How do I fix this?

Comment: I understand that there is some language barrier here but I don't understand what the last line in your question is asking?

Comment: @Shawn Sorry. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If images come from server then try to set Adapter in asyncTask OnPost()

Comment: Any error messages occur when loading large images?   Any logcat that might help diagnose?